# How do Fortran and MPI_Reduce deal with integer overflow?

Tags: casting, integer, fortran

Following [this thread](https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/questions/25494/checksum-of-a-distributed-variable), I want to cast a single / double precision real number "AA" into an integer "II" to compute the checksum of a distributed variable.

Following comments, I have used the intrinsic 'transfer' and rewritten completely this post. Below is a small fortran module that can be used to compute checksums of distributed arrays which depends on the library [2DECOMP&FFT](http://www.2decomp.org/). The module seems to work on my workstation (gfortran 4.9.2, openmpi 1.6.5, 4 processors). Any comment / remark that may improve the portability of the code will be highly appreciated. Main question regarding portability is: do fortran and MPI_reduce deal with integer overflow in the same way according to standards?

```
module checksum

   use MPI
   use decomp_2d, only : mytype, nrank, &
   xsize, ysize, zsize, &
   transpose_x_to_y, transpose_y_to_z, &
   transpose_z_to_y, transpose_y_to_x

   implicit none

   private ! Make everything private unless declared public

   real(mytype), parameter :: xx=1.

   integer, parameter, public :: chksum_size = size(transfer(xx,(/0,0/)))

   integer, dimension(chksum_size) :: chkr1, chkr2, chkr3

   logical, save :: chksum_is_working

   ! Temporary work variables / arrays
   integer :: code
   integer, dimension(chksum_size) :: tmprchk

   public :: init_chksum, chksum, equal_chksum

   contains

   !
   ! Function to compute the checksum of a real 3D array var
   !
   function chksum(var,nx,ny,nz)
      integer, intent(in) :: nx, ny, nz
      real(mytype), dimension(nx,ny,nz), intent(in) :: var
      integer, dimension(chksum_size) :: chksum

      tmprchk = sum(transfer(var,(/0,0/)))
      call MPI_ALLREDUCE(tmprchk,chksum,chksum_size,MPI_INTEGER,MPI_SUM,MPI_COMM_WORLD,code)

   end function chksum

   !
   ! Subroutine to make sure input arrays have the same checksum
   ! First / second / third array are in X / Y / Z pencil
   ! If switch is provided, reference array is var3.
   !    Otherwise, reference array is var1
   !
   subroutine equal_chksum(var1, var2, var3, switch)
      real(mytype), dimension(xsize(1),xsize(2),xsize(3)), intent(inout) :: var1
      real(mytype), dimension(ysize(1),ysize(2),ysize(3)), intent(inout) :: var2
      real(mytype), dimension(zsize(1),zsize(2),zsize(3)), intent(inout) :: var3
      logical, optional, intent(in) :: switch

      if (chksum_is_working) then ! compute checksums
         chkr1 = chksum(var1,xsize(1),xsize(2),xsize(3))
         chkr2 = chksum(var2,ysize(1),ysize(2),ysize(3))
         chkr3 = chksum(var3,zsize(1),zsize(2),zsize(3))
      else ! generate checksums
         chkr1 = 1
         chkr2 = 2
         chkr3 = 3
      endif

      if (present(switch)) then
         if (any(chkr3.ne.chkr2)) call transpose_z_to_y(var3,var2)
         if (any(chkr3.ne.chkr1)) call transpose_y_to_x(var2,var1)
      else
         if (any(chkr1.ne.chkr2)) call transpose_x_to_y(var1,var2)
         if (any(chkr1.ne.chkr3)) call transpose_y_to_z(var2,var3)
      endif

   end subroutine equal_chksum

   !
   ! Subroutine used to check we have a working checksum
   !
   subroutine init_chksum(var1,var2,var3)
      real(mytype), dimension(xsize(1),xsize(2),xsize(3)), intent(out) :: var1
      real(mytype), dimension(ysize(1),ysize(2),ysize(3)), intent(out) :: var2
      real(mytype), dimension(zsize(1),zsize(2),zsize(3)), intent(out) :: var3

      ! Same random data inside all arrays
      call random_number(var1)
      call transpose_x_to_y(var1,var2)
      call transpose_y_to_z(var2,var3)

      ! Compute checksums
      chkr1 = chksum(var1,xsize(1),xsize(2),xsize(3))
      chkr2 = chksum(var2,ysize(1),ysize(2),ysize(3))
      chkr3 = chksum(var3,zsize(1),zsize(2),zsize(3))

      ! Check checksums
      if (any(chkr1.ne.chkr2).or.any(chkr1.ne.chkr3)) then
         chksum_is_working = .false.
         if (nrank.eq.0) print *,'Checksums based on integer overflow do not work'
      else
         chksum_is_working = .true.
      endif

   end subroutine init_chksum

end module checksum
```

Comment: What do you mean by "cast"?  You want to use the same bit pattern rather than value (such as with `transfer`)?

Comment: @francescalus thanks, I did not know about transfer, it is exactly what I need. Is it standard / portable?

Comment: You should anderstand that the  word *cast* is ambiguous and you simply MUST explain what exactly you do with some code. For example in C++ there is reinterpret_cast, dynamic_cast, static_cast and more http://stackoverflow.com/questions/332030/when-should-static-cast-dynamic-cast-const-cast-and-reinterpret-cast-be-used We can't tell from a crystal ball which kind of cast you mean.

Comment: @VladimirF reinterpret_cast seems to correspond, question updated

Comment: If you want to sum the bits then are those bits different in an integer than in a float? Note that IBTEST will will tell you if a bit is high or low.

Comment: sems like he edited it into a completely different question

Comment: Please really do not do this. Do not change existing questions so drastically. Normally I would roll back your edit, but there is an answer to your new question now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*do fortran and MPI_reduce deal with integer overflow in the same way according to standards?*

Neither the Fortran standard nor the MPI 3.0 standard even mentions integer overflow so you are at the mercy of the implementers.

However, I see you are only using integers of default *kind*, use a larger integer kind for intermediate results and you can implement your own overflow detection.

Answer (score 1):

Integer overflow is not defined by the Fortran standard. In C signed integer overflow is *undefined behaviour*.

If you enable undefined behaviour santizations in gfortran, your program will be stopped with an error message. (Happened to me when I was using a 3rd party random number generator.)

You can perform the operation using larger integers and crop the result or call a C function which uses unsigned integers. Integer overflow is only well defined for signed integers.